# Export google scholar citations to latex

Tags: cv

I'm just wondering whether there is a way to export my google scholar publications to a certain latex format. Namely, I am building a latex resume now and would list all the google scholar publications to it. Manual adding seems too complicate to do.

Comment: Use `biblatex` in conjunction with `biber`. Just like any other bibliography.

Comment: could you be more detailed or offering an answer +1. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to export your Google scholar citations to a .bib file all in one.
Assume you already have a Google scholar account.

1.Google scholar->settings->Bibliography manager->show links to import citations to bibtex.
2.Google scholar->my citations->click any one of your citations->Export(left bottom)->Export all my articls->click save.

Just found it. It's that wonderful.

Comment: They might have changed the interface, after you click on a citation, you cannot export all. Instead, use the checkbox to select all, and then on top the export option appears.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to import them all in one fell swoop, but you can import them individually without too much trouble.

Enter your name into Google Scholar. For each one of your publications that shows up, click on the 'Cite' link just beneath it. In the resulting pop-up box, click on 'Import into BiBTeX' (bottom left). Then a page will show up with an entry for your publication formatted in the .bib-file format. You can then copy and paste this into your .bib file and use this to make your CV.